# SlowCheetah not transforming file after removing App.Config from Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, slowcheetah

I have a solution with 5 projects and am using Visual Studio 2017.  The latest version of SlowCheetah (v3.0.61) is installed and transformations in all but one projects are working (meaning the output files are getting transformed and created properly).  However, for one of the projects the transform previews correctly, yet the output file does not get transformed.  This seemed to start happening when I removed the App.Config files from source control.  I've tried adding back to source control, but that didn't resolve the problem.  I've looked at all of the posts here, and I've verified everything is in place (most posts are for older versions and some comments are noted as out of date).  I've turned on the verbose build option and tried to look through it, but it is massive I didn't find anything that jumps out.  I saw one comment with the "normal" build option that the transform for the project in question was "successful" but it clearly is not creating the output file the same as the transform preview shows in solution explorer.  Is there some hook in the the build process that can let me step through the transform?

How can I troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: When you removed the `app.config` from source control was it also removed from the the project (even if only temporarily)?

Comment: Yes, because I had initially got bad info on how to remove from source control, it was temporarily removed from the project.  I have added it back.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra element added in the `.csproj` file's entry for the `app.config` file (example from one of my project files):

```
<None Include="App.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
```

Try removing the SlowCheetah NuGet package from the project and then adding it back. Otherwise you could edit the project file (version control from before the `app.config` was removed could help here).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have already tried removing the SlowCheetah NuGet package and adding it back, to no avail.  My project file includes the elements above, so this is not the problem either.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: uninstalling/adding SlowCheetah nuget pckg worked ty!